# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/connector/catalog/TableProvider

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

i am trying to alter the delta table using spark sql query in java code.
but when i am excuting my jar at cluster i am getting error like :
org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/connector/catalog/TableProvider

Comment: check if the spark sql library in your jar file. if not change (or remove the "provided" build scope from f.e. maven.

If you do not use maven, tell us which build tool you use.

Comment: yes i have that in my pom

Comment: remove the scope tag from the pom file. Maven should then package the libary into the jar file.

Comment: How do you run the Spark app? How do you run the query? Edit your question and add the answers. Thank you.